# Data parsing and sending from DICOM image in .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dicom, fo-dicom, dicomweb

I am currently working on a complete DICOM Web application based on .net core + Postgresql and OHIF viewer ( to render DICOM images). 
I've built a database with tables as Patient, Study, etc. and the attributes I am storing as PatientName, PatientDOB, etc. now while returning the json the output is also the same as

"PatientName" : "temp"

"PatientDOB" : "2332" 
..

but as DICOM viewers have a standard in which they recieve JSON objects as

{
     "0020000D": {

```
  "vr": "UI",

  "Value": [ "1.2.392.200036.9116.2.2.2.1762893313.1029997326.945873" ]
}
```

}

so I want to map my JSON input/output in such a way that while returning I return values in above Dicom format and while getting the data I store them as attributes (column names) and not as tags?

I am pretty new in .net core and Dicom web so how to proceed further with that? Also, I am using fo-Dicom to read the data from Dicom image.

Please provide some hint/code that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will propably store only few DicomTags into your database (the tags you need for doing a query against your database), but the viewer may want to have all the tags as Json. So I would not try to map your database-Jasons into Dicom-jsons, but I would use fo-dicom to generate the Json out of the DICOM file:

You need to add the nugeg package *fo-dicom.json* and then you can call

```
DicomDataset dataset = ... // wherever you get your DICOM file
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset, new JsonDicomConverter());
```

or the othe way round, if you want to convert such a DICOM conformant json into a DicomDataset

```
string json = ... // wherever you get the json from
DicomDataset dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DicomDataset>(json, new JsonDicomConverter());
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to integrate this with my database as this extracts all the info but when i need some specific query how to do that ?

Comment: Also I am getting JsonDicomConverter could not be found are you missing any assmebly refrence? What header file i need??

Answer (score 0):

OHIF Viewer supports the standard DICOMweb WADO-RS JSON metadata format in addition to the custom format you mentioned in your question. This means you can use any DICOMweb server such as Orthanc, DCM4CHE or [DICOMcloud](https://github.com/DICOMcloud/DICOMcloud)

[DICOMcloud](https://github.com/DICOMcloud/DICOMcloud) may fit your scenario better as it uses fo-dicom. However, it currently only support MS SQL Server and .NET 4.6. (there is an effort to support mySQL but it is not 100% completed)

If you still want to write your own, you can look of how it is implemented and adapt it to your own solution.

[Disclosure] I am the author of DICOMcloud

Comment: I am building my project with the help of yours, I am just stuck at this part!